# Bessel function solution check

Tags: bessel-functions

I'm pretty sure the Bessel function $J_0(x)$ should solve the equation:

$$ x^2 \frac{d^2 f}{d x^2} + x \frac{d f}{dx} + x^2 f = 0 $$

according to wikipedia this is the standard form of a bessel function differential equation. However, when I go to check this solution, using the identities:

$$ \frac{d}{dz} J_0(x) = - J_1(x) $$
and 
$$ \frac{d}{dz} J_1(x) = J_0(x) - \frac{1}{2} J_1(x) $$

I get

$$ x^2 \frac{d^2 J_0}{dx^2 } + x \frac{d J_0}{dx} + x^2 J_0 = 0 $$

$$ -x^2 \frac{d }{dx } J_1(x) - x J_1(x) + x^2 J_0 = 0 $$

$$ -x^2 \left (  J_0(x) - \frac{1}{2} J_1(x) \right ) - x J_1(x) + x^2 J_0 = 0 $$

$$\left ( \frac{x}{2} - 1 \right ) x J_1(x) = 0 $$

However, this does not seem to be true, where am I going wrong?

Comment: The following is not true:
$$\frac{d}{dx}J_1(x)=J_0(x)-\frac{1}{2}J_1(x)$$

Comment: @projectilemotion my source for that is http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/20/01/02/0001/

Comment: @MikeFlynn That is a $z$ on the denominator, not a $2$.

Comment: Your third equation should be
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{z} J_{1}(z)+ J'_{1}(z)=J_{0}(z).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: ahhhhhh thank you